# Building simulator for creating LAN

Tags: java, network-programming, lan

I want to create a simulator which consist of toolbars. The Toolbars have some components like computer , router, modem,cable . Using drag and drop facilities it creates a LAN network. After creating a LAN network, we will pass some inputs from one machine to another. After the inputs have reached the other machine it will generate a report(Time required).

Which Technology should I use? (I have a Java background.)
 How should I implement this?

Any help or pointer really appreciated.

P.S.: I really appreciate it if anybody can edit or improve tags.

**EDIT**

One way is using awt, swing, and applet, which is implemented for logic circuit like GAt, Flipflop.

http://www.tetzl.de/logicsim_applet.html

Is any other alternative to implement this?

Comment: I have no clue what you're actually trying to do. What do you mean by "creating LAN network"?!

Comment: See the title - he wants to create a LAN simulator.

Comment: This should be moved to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

This is a very wide question. I think you should start by studying existing open source simulators and their design.